# I'm Suffering with the problem in my django code for uploading the code of the image into the database?

Tags: python, django

Whenever i tried to upload the image through the form it gives me an error which is multivalue dictionary key error. GIVEN BELOW.....
and this image will show on the other side of the project let's say user side. Any hints  ..___i also added the full code of my html page....

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /hosteladmin/messfood
'photo'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/hosteladmin/messfood
Django Version: 2.2.4
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:    
'photo'
Exception Location: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py in __getitem__, line 80
Python Executable:  C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.4
Python Path:    
['D:\\django project\\hostel_final',
 'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32',
 'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
Server time:    Mon, 11 Nov 2019 10:07:52 +0000
```

Please Help me out on this,i shall be very thankfull

```
VIEWS FILE CODE:-
def messfood(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        dn=request.POST['name']
        dp=request.POST['price']
        ft=request.POST['dfgtime']
        fd=request.POST['sdday']
        s=Fooddetials()
        s.dimage = request.FILES["photo"]
        s.dname=dn
        s.dprice=dp
        s.food_timing=ft
        s.food_day=fd
        s.save()
        return render(request,'hosteladmin/messfood.html')
    else:
        return render(request,'hosteladmin/messfood.html')
```

```
HTML FORM CODE:-
{% extends 'hosteladmin/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="card">
        <div class="card-header card-header-primary">
          <h4 class="card-title">Add Mess Food Service</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <form action="{% url 'messfood' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <label class="bmd-label-floating">Dish Image</label>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <input type="file" name="dimage">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
                    <label class="bmd-label-floating">Dish Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required="">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
                        <label class="bmd-label-floating">Dish Price</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price" required="">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
                          <label class="bmd-label-floating">Food Time</label><br>
                          <select class="form-control "  name="dfgtime" data-style="btn btn-link" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">

                           <option value="1">BreakFast</option>
                           <option value="1">Lunch</option>   
                           <option value="1">Dinner</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
                              <label class="bmd-label-floating">Day</label><br>
                              <select class="form-control " name="sdday" data-style="btn btn-link" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                               <option value="1">Sunday</option>
                               <option value="1">Monday</option>
                               <option value="1">Tuesday</option>
                               <option value="1">Wednesday</option>
                               <option value="1">Thrusday</option>
                               <option value="1">Friday</option>
                               <option value="1">Saturday</option>
                              </select>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>          
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Add Detials</button>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
{% endblock %}
```

```
MODELS FILE CODE:-

class Fooddetials(models.Model):
    dimage=models.ImageField(upload_to='fooddetails/')
    dname=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dprice=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    food_timing=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    food_day=models.CharField(max_length=200,default="")
```

```
ROOT DIRECTORY IN SETTINGS OF THE PROJECT:-
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') 
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: is it a multipart form

Comment: did you add enctype='multipart/form-data' this in form tag

Comment: can you add your complete html form?

Comment: do as @pavan mentioned. change you form starting tag with `<form action="{% url 'messfood' %}" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' >`

Comment: thank you guys  for the help

Answer (score 1):

put it in a try block and see

```
    try:
        s.dimage = request.FILES or None['photo']
    except TypeError:
        s.dimage = None
```

Comment: its working but the problem is its not getting the image from the form and in the database the data is saving in the table without the image (The image field is Empty)

Comment: try to call it directly, similar to the name and price